# Error when backprop: One of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch, ocr

When I try to run `bash scripts/train_uspto_joint_chartok_1m680k.sh` in [repo](https://github.com/thomas0809/MolScribe), i stuck with this error:

*RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.LongTensor [1, 123]] is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).*

This error occurs in **train function** (in file train.py):

```
def train_fn(train_loader, encoder, decoder, criterion, encoder_optimizer, decoder_optimizer, epoch,
             encoder_scheduler, decoder_scheduler, scaler, device, global_step, SUMMARY, args):
    # scaler is a function of AMP that helps speed up training but still keeps performance


    # Computes and stores the average and current value
    batch_time = AverageMeter() 
    data_time = AverageMeter()
    loss_meter = LossMeter() # inherit from AverageMeter
    # switch to train mode
    encoder.train()
    decoder.train()
    
    start = end = time.time()
    encoder_grad_norm = decoder_grad_norm = 0

    for step, (indices, images, refs) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # measure data loading time
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)
        images = images.to(device)
        batch_size = images.size(0)
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=args.fp16):
            features, hiddens = encoder(images, refs)
            results = decoder(features, hiddens, refs) 
            losses = criterion(results, refs)
            loss = sum(losses.values())
        # record loss
        loss_meter.update(loss, losses, batch_size)
        if args.gradient_accumulation_steps > 1:
            loss = loss / args.gradient_accumulation_steps

        ###### Error indicated here ######
        scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        ##################################

        if (step + 1) % args.gradient_accumulation_steps == 0:
            scaler.unscale_(encoder_optimizer)
            scaler.unscale_(decoder_optimizer)
            encoder_grad_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(encoder.parameters(), args.max_grad_norm)
            decoder_grad_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(decoder.parameters(), args.max_grad_norm)
            scaler.step(encoder_optimizer)
            scaler.step(decoder_optimizer)
            scaler.update()
            encoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
            decoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
            encoder_scheduler.step()
            decoder_scheduler.step()
            global_step += 1
        # measure elapsed time
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()
        if step % args.print_freq == 0 or step == (len(train_loader) - 1):
            loss_str = ' '.join([f'{k}:{v.avg:.4f}' for k, v in loss_meter.subs.items()])
            print_rank_0('Epoch: [{0}][{1}/{2}] '
                         'Data {data_time.avg:.3f}s ({sum_data_time}) '
                         'Run {remain:s} '
                         'Loss: {loss.avg:.4f} ({loss_str}) '
                         'Grad: {encoder_grad_norm:.3f}/{decoder_grad_norm:.3f} '
                         'LR: {encoder_lr:.6f} {decoder_lr:.6f}'
            .format(
                epoch + 1, step, len(train_loader), batch_time=batch_time,
                data_time=data_time, loss=loss_meter, loss_str=loss_str,
                sum_data_time=asMinutes(data_time.sum),
                remain=timeSince(start, float(step + 1) / len(train_loader)),
                encoder_grad_norm=encoder_grad_norm,
                decoder_grad_norm=decoder_grad_norm,
                encoder_lr=encoder_scheduler.get_lr()[0],
                decoder_lr=decoder_scheduler.get_lr()[0]))
            loss_meter.reset()
        if args.train_steps_per_epoch != -1 and (
                step + 1) // args.gradient_accumulation_steps == args.train_steps_per_epoch:
            break

    return loss_meter.epoch.avg, global_step
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qk/Documents/FTECH/OCR/MolScribe/train.py", line 612, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/qk/Documents/FTECH/OCR/MolScribe/train.py", line 598, in main
    train_loop(args, train_df, valid_df, aux_df, tokenizer, args.save_path)
  File "/home/qk/Documents/FTECH/OCR/MolScribe/train.py", line 380, in train_loop
    avg_loss, global_step = train_fn(
  File "/home/qk/Documents/FTECH/OCR/MolScribe/train.py", line 221, in train_fn
    scaler.scale(loss).backward()
  File "/home/qk/anaconda3/envs/MolScribe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 488, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/home/qk/anaconda3/envs/MolScribe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 197, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.LongTensor [1, 123]] is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

I tried to add: `with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)` to debug and it returned the error with the same traceback:

*RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.LongTensor [1, 123]] is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!*

HOPE ANYONE CAN HELP ME! LY

Comment: You should include the backtrace from your new error (try to reduce it to valuable parts). Rising an Issue on Github would also be beneficial

Comment: I updated traceback